# getting ValueError: 'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a dictionary where is a key is the node name and the value is the node position. the dictionary `(dicts)` looks like this:

```
{0: array([ 360, 259, 364, 259, 364, 261, 360, 261]), 
 1: array([ 380, 258, 385, 258, 385, 262, 380, 262]), 
 2: array([ 365, 258, 370, 258, 370, 262, 365, 262]), 
 3: array([ 386, 256, 393, 256,393, 260,386, 260])}
```

I am trying to plot a graph using networkx but I got error:

> ValueError: 'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2

My code:

```
  g = torch_geometric.utils.to_networkx(data, to_undirected=True)
  plt.figure(len(data))
  nx.draw(g, pos=dicts, with_labels=True)
  plt.show()
```

Comment: The function is looking for each dictionary value (node locations) to be a list or array of 2 items (x and y coordinates).

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the position should contain x,y locations, while your data has more values. One way is to apply the appropriate dimensionality reduction, but as a shortcut the script below just uses the first two values:

```py
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

data = {
    0: np.array([360, 259, 364, 259, 364, 261, 360, 261]),
    1: np.array([380, 258, 385, 258, 385, 262, 380, 262]),
    2: np.array([365, 258, 370, 258, 370, 262, 365, 262]),
    3: np.array([386, 256, 393, 256, 393, 260, 386, 260]),
}

data_truncated = {k: v[:2] for k, v in data.items()}

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(range(4))

nx.draw(G, pos=data_truncated, with_labels=True)
```

Comment: Are the first two values enough to represent the position (location) of the node??

Comment: That depends on specific of your data. If this is some high-dimensional data, then it's better to apply dimensionality reduction.

Comment: Sir, if the position coordinates look like this: (1022, 201, 1366, 724). Is it possible to represent it in terms of xy coordinates??

Comment: Yes, but there is a broad range of algorithms to reduce dimensions, this could be a good starting point: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/unsupervised_reduction.html