# Python draw graph in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have two lists where the first list has the nodes and the second list has the distance between the nodes (values). How to draw a graph in Networkx using those lists?

first list:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

second list:

```
[0.0009, 0.3338, 0.1880, 0.3342, 0.1883, 0.1488]
```

My code:

```
dicts = {}
  keys = range(4)
  for i in keys:
        dicts[i] = values[i]
  print(dicts)

g = torch_geometric.utils.to_networkx(data, to_undirected=True)
plt.figure(len(data))
nx.draw(g, pos=dicts, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

I got this output:

```
{0: 0.000926, 1: 0.33381733, 2: 0.18802813, 3: 0.33418187}

NetworkXError: Node 4 has no position.
```

Comment: How do the weights in the second list map to the nodes in the first list?

Comment: [0.0009, 0.3338, 0.1880] are the distance from 0 to [1,2,3]. [0.3342, 0.1883] are the distance from 1 to [2,3]. [0.1488] distance from 2 to [3]

Comment: Are you sure your input graph has exactly four nodes?

Comment: Yes Sir. I have only 4 nodes.

Comment: This seems related to [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70523152/10693596), and I suspect the `data` has more than 4 nodes (or they are numbered starting from 1).